# Exposing /swagger endpoint from C# serverless application in AWS API Gateway protected by API Key

Tags: c#, aws-lambda, swagger, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless

I used a [C# AWS serverless application template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/lambda-build-test-severless-app.html) to create my API (ASP.NET Core API with controllers) and expose it in AWS API Gateway. The API Gateway is protected with API key.

Now I want to add Swagger and view the Swagger page in the browser. I added XML comments to my C# controller and it works locally. However, the API Gateway is protected with API Key that must be passed in the header. Thus, the Swagger page in cloud is  inaccessible through the browser (well unless you send the header in your browser).

Here is how the resources look like:
[image]

The `/{proxy+}` is my Lambda function (C# asp.net core api application)

The Cloud Formation template looks like this:

```
"Resources": {
"AspNetCoreFunction": {
  "Type": "AWS::Serverless::Function",
  "Properties": {
    "Handler": "AWSServerless1::AWSServerless1.LambdaEntryPoint::FunctionHandlerAsync",
    "Runtime": "dotnet6",
    "CodeUri": "",
    "MemorySize": 256,
    "Timeout": 30,
    "Role": null,
    "Policies": [
      "AWSLambda_FullAccess"
    ],
    "Events": {
      "ProxyResource": {
        "Type": "Api",
        "Properties": {
          "Path": "/{proxy+}",
          "Method": "ANY"
        }
      },
      "RootResource": {
        "Type": "Api",
        "Properties": {
          "Path": "/",
          "Method": "ANY"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

},

How can I update the Cloud Formation template/API Gateway settings to expose this single /swagger endpoint (the endpoint is part of the Lambda function). So that it will be accessible without API-Key.

Answer (score 1):

We had exactly the same issue and rather than try to configure separate API gateway rules for the swagger endpoint, it's far easier to simply install a browser extension that automatically adds the necessary API key into the headers.  (You will need the API key to be able to invoke the API from the swagger page anyway).  You wouldn't want un-authorised users to be able able to access your swagger page, so I would recommend keeping it protected by the API key.

We use ModHeader: https://docs.modheader.com/using-modheader/about-modheader

Answer (score 0):

I found a setup that allows to access `/swagger` endpoint without the API KEY, in case someone is looking for the same.

Set the `/api/{proxy+}/ANY` to require the API KEY.
The `/swagger` - without the API KEY.

[image]